# How to use "newly" in a sentence?

Tags: grammar, word-usage, meaning-in-context

Please explain the word "newly" for me. Does it mean:

- 1. It's 10:00 a.m now and I finished my homework at 9:55 a.m. So can I say "I newly finished my homework"?
- 2. It's 10:00 am now and I finished my homework yesterday. So can I say "I newly finished my homework"?

Which sentence is correct?

Answer (score 1):

The word *newly* sounds strange here and *recently* fits the context better:

> I recently finished my homework.

The difference between the two words is explained [here](https://wikidiff.com/newly/recently):

> As adverbs the difference between *newly* and *recently* is that newly is in a new manner while recently is in the recent past

Then, whether you consider *yesterday* or *five minutes ago* to be *recently* depends on the context and both would be correct.

Comment: "A newly-added address." = "A recently-added address." Here the two words are the same